# iOS iPhone app doesnt fill screen on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode7

I have an iOS app which resizes/looks fine between iPhone 4 through to iPhone 6s Plus. However, when I run the same app on any iPad device I get black bars on all sides of my view. I've tried several things to fix it but nothing has works. Here is what it looks like

[image: Black Bars on all sides]

**I checked the following settings:**

- General>Deployment Info>Devices: iPhone
- Autolayout turned on
- Size Classes Disabled
- No warnings in interface builder
- Problem exists on ios 8.0 and 9.0
- Works fine in iPhone devices
- Xcode 7.2 (started project in Xcode 6.4)
- Launch Screen.storyboard exists

Comment: You need to make your app **UNIVERSAL**. It is the third option after "iPhone" and "iPad". It means that it supposrts **both**.

Comment: @NicolasMiari why? I only want it to run on iPhone

Comment: Because that it how iPhone-only apps are displayed on iPad. Only "iPad" apps or "Universal" apps fill the whole iPad screen.

Comment: You can not prevent an iPhone-only app from being installed on an iPad: The iPad is designed to run iPhone-only apps in 1x or 2x mode since the beginning (it "simulates" the iPhone). The iPhone, on the other side, will not install iPad-only apps. That is how it works.

Comment: @NicolasMiari  even on 2x mode it doesnt fill the screen completely. Shouldnt it still fill the screen with the app in 2x mode?

Comment: No; 2x mode is just a "quick and dirty zoom", for convenience. It is still rendered as if running on an iPhone (originally, 320x480). iPhone and iPad have different aspect ratios,etc.

Comment: It is not supposed to fill the screen or otherwise fake a "true" iPad app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *I only want it to run on iPhone...*

   Paragraph 2.10 of [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

   > 2.10
   >   iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
2. *iOS iPhone app doesn't fill screen on iPad*

   That **is** the definition of an app not targeted for iPad, as explained above in the accurate comments from [@NicolasMiari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433373/nicolasmiari).

---

On the other hand, if you have a genuine reason to **not** target iPad, because the hardware does not provide a key capability you need, you can explicitly request for that capability, and your app will not launch (nor be proposed on the App Store when browsed from that device).

Examples include SMS, Telephony, HealthKit. See the [Device Compatibility Matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html).